# SQL order by issue does not display correctly in datatables

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I have a table which contains information on all my system's users.  One of the rows in this table is named `is_active`, which contains a simple string stating ACTIVE or INACTIVE.

I am building a panel in which an administrator can list all the information of all users.  This information is being displayed by the datatable library.  I would like the datatable to first show all active users, and then the inactive ones afterwards.

Unfortunately, my query is not returning the information correctly.

#### CODE

```
public function get_all_users(){
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY is_active DESC");
    
    try{
        $query->execute();
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }       
    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

As of now, the output is not filtered within groupings, and can have a row of : Active, active, inactive,inactive, active.inactive, etc....

I'm thinking this should have nothing to do with the datatables plugin, but rather my query.  Can someone help?  Thanks in advance!

#### TABLE STRUCTURE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `direct_phone` varchar(21) NOT NULL,
  `ext_num` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `cellphone` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `num_loads_booked` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `security_level` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `last_logged_in` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=24 ;
```

Comment: Can you paste the table definition ?

Comment: I will suggest you that you have to use "bit" datatype for the is_active column that will be more secured and will be the proper datatype for that column.

Comment: @Hardik there are going to be someother types added in the future which will be incompatible with a bit, int or bool type unfortunately

Comment: @GiulioDeMarco question has been updated

Comment: but in this column you will only insert either Active OR Inactive & bit or bool will be the perfect.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you have [case sensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) collation turned on and different cases (`active`, `ACTIVE`, ...) used as `is_active` values. Try running:

```
SELECT 'a' > 'A', 'a' < 'A', 'a' = 'A';
```

If you get `(1,0,0)` you are running case sensitive collation and if `(0,0,1)` case insensitive, or check:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
```

For me it's `utf8_general_ci` -> `_ci` means `case insensitive`.

---

Let's put that aside, storing binary value (*is_active = yes or no*) in text field... You are using up to 10B to store 1 bit.

If you insist on using text (human eye friendly) column, use [`ENUM('active', 'inactive')`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) (enums are internally represented by numbers, so look up is faster).

Or even better use [`BOOL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) (which is alias for `TINYINT(1)`). Than you have to use:

```c
print(row->GetInt("is_active") ? 'ACTIVE' : 'INACTIVE')
// Instead of
print(row->GetString("is_active"))
```

Which is a bit longer, but it's faster when evaluation expression an so on:

```c
if( user->is_active)
// Instead of
if( user->is_active == "active")
```

Migration for you should be also quite easy:

```sql
ALTER TABLE users CHANGE is_active _is_active VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE users ADD is_active BOOL DEFAULT 0 BEFORE _is_active;
UPDATE users SET is_active = (
    CONVERT(_is_active USING latin1) COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci = 'active'
);
-- Check results here
ALTER TABLE users DROP COLUMNS _is_active;
```

Comment: I agree about using lengthy strings to represent only two values. For databases (like Oracle) without bit, bool or enums, the old reliable `char(1)` with values 'Y' or 'N' is good. It is also human friendly, especially as the name of the field, `is_active`, begs for a yes/no result.